# Link/Compile a Polymer or Web Components template to Angularjs Scope

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I have a [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) component (web component) and I have put an angular controller inside of it, like so:

```
<polymer-element name="x-display"
  attributes="title body">
  <template>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <p>{{body}}</p>
    <p ng-controller="XDisplayController" ng-bind="text"></p>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('x-display', {
      title: "",
      body: ""
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The `<x-display>` is being placed on the page like this:

```
<div ng-controller="PeopleController">
    <h1>People</h1>
    <input ng-model="query" type="text">
    <x-display ng-repeat="p in people | filter:query" 
        title="{{ p.name }}" body="{{ p.body }}"></x-display>
</div>
```

This is all pretty cool. With one exception it behaves exactly the same as you'd expect, placing a whole bunch of `<x-display>` tags, one for each person, and filling them with the correct values. I make the call to `Polymer` default the values to null so that the `{{ p.value }}` occurrences don't flash up but aside from that it's nice and simple.

The problem is the nested `XDisplayController` never get's parsed by Angularjs, and so never becomes a real controller. If I defined it like this then:

```
function XDisplayController($scope) {
    $scope.text = "blah blah";
    console.log("this never gets printed");
}
```

It is left sadly untouched.

How would I go about making angularjs aware of the template and ideally how would I make it inherit the parent scope so it behaved exactly as if had been placed on the page as if by an angular directive?

I suspect it might have something to do with [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) but I can't get it to work.

Oh, I should mention that Polymer has [lifecycle callbacks](http://www.polymer-project.org/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods), which would probably be the appropriate place to call whatever linking angularjs code.

Edit: I tried CodeHater's code, changing element.contents() to element.context.impl and got the following error:

```
An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

I think this is to do with Shadow DOM and how the tags created by polymer have their own context.

Comment: Are you creating that polymer-element from within a directive?

Comment: No. In my <head> I have <link rel="import" href="elements.html">, where my polymer-template is located. So what you see in the first code area is an html component import, which I use instead of an angular directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how to fix this from the Angular side...

**Using Angular inside of a Polymer element**

At the moment, `<polymer-element>` is a separate world from Angular's. Because Polymer creates Shadow DOM from the first `<template>` in an element, the errors you're seeing come from Angular's compiler not finding the `ng-controller` within the Shadow DOM. It expects to parse and run in the global context. The workaround with `element.contents()` looks interesting, but that call doesn't understand how to traverse into Shadow DOM AFAICT.

Another gotcha with using Angular *inside* Polymer is that each has its own (similar) data binding and expression syntax. This will create collisions if you try to mix and match.

More on this: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/polymer-dev/s_wH7gaCQZ0/discussion

**Using Polymer elements inside of an Angular app**

You should be able to create a Polymer element, give it an API, publish some properties, and reuse them in an Angular app. The reverse (using Angular inside of Polymer elements) is trickier b/c of the Shadow DOM issues I mentioned.

I haven't tried this, so you may see some weirdness with the polyfills trying to do their thing. Polymer -> Angular will definitely work with the native APIs.

**Building component based apps**

All this said, if we start building apps that are component based, everything will be hunky dory. You use directives to write components using Angular; Polymer to write web components. Use them harmoniously together on the outside b/c they're compartmentalized building blocks for an entire app. So instead of writing controllers for sections of markup, write components!

---

Moral of this response: I would ask in the Angular group when they expect to support Shadow DOM :)

Answer (score 1):

I am totally new to Polymer but I would ask you to try something like this:

```
<x-display polymer-directive ng-repeat="p in people | filter:query" 
    title="{{ p.name }}" body="{{ p.body }}"></x-display>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('polymerDirective', function($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);

            /* if polymer dont render the template before 
               the directive is linked you can just delay 
               the compilation a bit */             
            $timeout(function(){
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            },1000);

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: So that seems to be on to something, since the code is getting run every time one of the templates is made, but it isn't quite working. I think it's the element.contents() that isn't correct. I can also confirm that $timeout was needed to get the inner contents, although I think that might be due to the polyfill. Behavior may vary for natively implemented web components.

Comment: I changed element.contents() to element.context.impl.innerHTML and the XDisplayController is now being evaluated (it prints to console, indicating it was initialized for each x-display). Unfortunately the ng-bind isn't working, nothing is being data-binded to the contents of the <p> tag.